# Fixing a .ts file with Checksum error

Tags: video, mpeg

I have got a 8GB .ts video file, unfortunately when I tried to copy it from my hard disk to my 16GB USB thumb drive, I got an error at 60% which seems to be a file checksum error (strangely, I found no error when I checked the disk, so it is not likely a bad sector, and I can view the video with MPC before and after that point, the video just stops when coming across that 60% point).

I tried using Project X to see if the file can be repaired, but as expected, there is an error once the software reads the file at 60%. So my thought is to split the file into 2 separate parts, Part 1 before the 60% mark and Part 2 starts after the 60%, simply using byte-by-byte read-write, hence skipping the problem part.

Part 1 works ok, and Part 2 doesn't because the header is missing. But is it possible to fix Part 2 and use some software to add the header back? People said Project X is powerful, but I don't know if it can solve my problem (and if so, how). Any guidance is welcomed. Thanks!

Edit: I used ffmpeg to check and get this error report:
Full report on http://pastebin.com/yU6Y36Yw

`[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] no frame!
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] no frame!
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] no frame!
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000042c480] no frame!
[mpegts @ 00000000004f8fe0] start time for stream 4 is not set in estimate_timin
gs_from_pts
[mpegts @ 00000000004f8fe0] start time for stream 5 is not set in estimate_timin
gs_from_pts
[mpegts @ 00000000004f8fe0] start time for stream 6 is not set in estimate_timin
gs_from_pts
[mpegts @ 00000000004f8fe0] PES packet size mismatch
    Last message repeated 3 times
Input #0, mpegts, from 'L:\HBPVR\TVClip\20170127.ts':
  Duration: 01:47:03.36, start: 0.083867, bitrate: 10069 kb/s
  Program 137
    Stream #0:0[0x30]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv,
bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc`

```
`Stream #0:1[0x40]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s`
`Stream #0:2[0x41]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s`
`Stream #0:3[0x42]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s`
`Stream #0:4[0x50](CHI): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)`
`Stream #0:5[0x51](ENG): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)`
`Stream #0:6[0x52](CHS): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)`
```

`Output #0, mpegts, to 'L:\HBPVR\TVClip\20170127h.ts':`
`Metadata:`
`encoder         : Lavf57.66.101`
`Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9]
, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc`
`Metadata:`
`encoder         : Lavc57.77.100 mpeg2video`
`Side data:`
`cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1`
`Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s`
`Metadata:`
`encoder         : Lavc57.77.100 mp2`
`Stream mapping:`
`Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg2video (native))`
`Stream #0:3 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> mp2 (native))`
`Press [q] to stop, [?] for help`
`[h264 @ 00000000022f9f20] co located POCs unavailable`
`Last message repeated 1 times`
`[h264 @ 00000000022fa8c0] mmco: unref short failure
frame=   40 fps=0.0 q=31.0 size=     651kB time=00:00:01.96 bitrate=2720.2kbits/
frame=   93 fps= 92 q=31.0 size=    1198kB time=00:00:04.08 bitrate=2406.4kbits/
frame=  136 fps= 90 q=31.0 size=    1554kB time=00:00:05.80 bitrate=2195.1kbits/
frame=  185 fps= 92 q=31.0 size=    1991kB time=00:00:07.76 bitrate=2102.1kbits/
[mpegts @ 00000000004f8fe0] PES packet size mismatch
[h264 @ 00000000022fad80] error while decoding MB 118 48, bytestream -72
[h264 @ 00000000022fad80] concealing 2331 DC, 2331 AC, 2331 MV errors in I frame
[ac3 @ 00000000022f6f00] incomplete frame
frame=  221 fps= 11 q=31.0 size=    2409kB time=00:00:09.20 bitrate=2145.2kbits/
L:\HBPVR\TVClip\20170127.ts: Permission denied
Last message repeated 6 times
frame=  227 fps= 11 q=31.0 Lsize=    2550kB time=00:00:09.48 bitrate=2203.5kbits
/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=0.46x
video:1917kB audio:408kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxin
g overhead: 9.644997%`

Comment: Try with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) on the full file. First `ffmpeg -i in.ts -c copy out.ts`. Else, `ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i in.ts -c copy out.ts`

Comment: @Mulvya I tried both commands, and both returned the error: [mpegts  at 000000000043a960] PES packet size mismatch
frame=111064 fps=1000 q=-1.0 size= 4625636kB time=01:03:29.35 bitrate=9947.4kbit
L:\HBPVR\TVClip\20170127.ts: Permission denied

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -ss 3800 -t 120 -i in.ts out.ts -report` and post the report file generated.

Comment: Paste the full report into your Q as code.

Comment: Full report, please. Use pastebin or similar if it's too big.

Comment: @Mulvya Added the link for the full report. Strangely using the latter command you provided, the detection stops at Frame 227, but using the former command, the detection stops at the error point which is around 1 hr 03 min.

Comment: In the latest command, ffmpeg is starting at 1h3m20s and stopping at roughly the same point as the first command. Now, some trial and error is needed. Run my last command, but experiment with the `ss` value till you get a playable output. Start with `3809` and increase it.

Comment: @Mulvya I have found a way to work around it, just using the dd command in linux to split files and skip the problem part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used the Windows version of the Linux command 'dd' to solve the above problem. Using the strategy stated in the question, I split the file into 2 parts, the first part up to 60%, the second part from 60% after the problem bytes until the end. The 2 resulting files can be read, without any need to add extra headers.

The previous attempt (I wrote a program to split the files into 2) failed, just because my compiler seems not supporting files larger than 2GB using fseek().

Comment: A lot of players have problems with file sizes over 2GB. Set file limits in your record program if this is s common problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had success using Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier to copy a corrupted file from a DVD (DVD was badly damaged) some years ago: https://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29

It at least gave me "complete" files, that I was then able to feed into other software to extract the still readable sections of video.